# linq query 'orderby' using multiple fields at SQLite plugin by MvvmCross doesn't work

Tags: linq, sqlite, xamarin, sql-order-by, mvvmcross

The query is the following:

```
var query = from c in _db.Table<Contact>()
            where c.FirstName.Contains("Alex")
            orderby c.Priority, c.FirstName, c.LastName
            select c;
```

Is it a limitation of SQLite, MvvmCross plugin? 
Should I go with .Syntax as a result?

```
Error CS1936: An implementation of `ThenBy' query expression pattern for source type `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.ITableQuery<Contact>' could not be found (CS1936)
```

Comment: Definitely *not* a limitation of SQLite itself... You can see [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite/blob/master/Sqlite/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite/BaseClasses.cs#L286)  that MvvmCross-SQLite implements `OrderBy`, but not `ThenBy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to handle this by specifying mutiple OrderBy methods:

```
var res = _db.Table<Contact>()
 .Where(c=> c.....)
 .OrderBy(c => c.Priority)
 .OrderBy(c => c.FirstName)
 .OrderBy(c => c.LastName)
 .Select(c=> c)
 .ToList();
```

Translated to the SQLite query:

```
SELECT * FROM "Contact"
WHERE ...
ORDER BY "Priority", "FirstName", "LastName"
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Are you sure this is the generated SQL query? That's not how `OrderBy` is supposed to work. In LINQ-to-objects this would only order by `LastName`.

Comment: it's a specific implementation of the SQLite MvvmCross plugin. I would glad to use `ThenBy` by it's not implemented (see the error from the question)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work around this limitation using a custom `IComparer<T>` for your Contact object.  Here is an [MSDN article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727) explaining how to do this. I would recommend using `IComparer<T>` instead of `IComparer`.  I think `IComparer<T>` did not exist when the article was written.